# Позиционирование flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

День добрый! Есть такая html конструкция

```
<div class="special">
    <div class="special__block-left">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/left.jpg" alt="left"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="special__block-center">
        <div class="special__block-center-top">
            <h1>Text</h1>
            <a href="#">Button</a>
        </div>
        <div class="special__block-center-bottom">
            <h1>Text</h1>
            <a href="#">Button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="special__block-right">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/right.jpg" alt="right"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как с помощью flexbox их позиционировать так, как на картинке ниже (извиняюсь за свои навыки Paint) на десктопе, планшете и мобильных устройствах? 1 и 4 блоки - изображения, 2 и 3 - текст с кнопкой, блок закрашен. Размеры одинковы 1 и 4, а также 2 и 3 блока (еще раз извиняюсь за Paint).
Спасибо за помощь!

[image: Пример реализации]

Comment: `direction: column;`, а дальше менять `order` у элементов в зависимости от экрана

Comment: @slippyk, в принципе вариант, но там будет муть с переносами между колонками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно.

В разметке расположить (1 2 (3 4)).

Для телефона. Всему `display: block` и оно само встанет.

Для остальных. Горизонтальный флексбокс.

Для планшета. Для контейнера 3 и 4 выставить `flex: 0 0 100%`, для общего контейнера разрешить перенос. Для самих 3 и 4 ширину по 50% любым способом.

Для десктопа. Переупорядочить элементы используя свойство `order`.

Лейаут выбирать на основе `min-width`, не перепутать порядок media-запросов (если они ограничивают ширину только с одного конца, то распространяются и на больший размер).

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, 
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.vblock {
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
}

.hblock {
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 674px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 670px;
    height: 320px;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 225px) and (max-width: 673px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 480px;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(4) {
    order: 4;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 224px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 220px;
    height: 960px;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(3) {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .block:nth-child(4) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block vblock">1</div>
  <div class="block vblock">2</div>
  <div class="block hblock">3</div>
  <div class="block hblock">4</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slippyk/s7jcgj2g/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.block {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.block--1,
.block--2 {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.block--3,
.block--4 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

/* tablet */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .container {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  
  .block--1 {
    order: 0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  
  .block--2 {
    order: 1;
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
  
  .container__inner {
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  .block--3,
  .block--4 {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}


/* mobile */

@media (max-width: 560px) {
  .block--1,
  .block--2,
  .block--3,
  .block--4 {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  
  .container__inner {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block block--1">1</div>
  <div class="container__inner">
    <div class="block block--3">3</div>
    <div class="block block--4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block block--2">2</div>
</div>
```